# Logging Web application using Spring AOP and AspectJ

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop

I'm new at Spring and JSF and my BOSS asked me add logging to a web application built with JSF Maven Spring here is my Code

LoggingBean.Java

```
 package ma.nawarit.logger;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import edu.emory.mathcs.backport.java.util.Arrays;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;



@Aspect
public class LoggerBean {

        private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
        //Before
        @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
        public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            //log.debug(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
            System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
            System.out.println("Method Name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            System.out.println("******");
        }

        //After
        @After("execution(public * *(..))")
        public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
            //log.debug(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
            System.out.println("logAfter() is running!");
            System.out.println("Method Name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            System.out.println("******");
        }

        //Log After Returning
        @AfterReturning("execution(public * *(..))")
        public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
            //log.debug(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
            System.out.println("logAfterReturning() is running!");
            System.out.println("Method Name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            System.out.println("Method returned value is : " + result);
            System.out.println("******");
        }

        //Log After Throwing Exception
        @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(public * *(..))",throwing= "error")
        public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {

            System.out.println("logAfterThrowing() is running!");
            System.out.println("Method Name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
            System.out.println("Exception : " + error);
            System.out.println("******");
        }

        //Log Arround Interceptor
        @Around("execution(public * *(..))")
           public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
                System.out.println("logAround() is running!");
                System.out.println("Method Name : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
                System.out.println("Method Arguments : " + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));

                System.out.println("Around before is running!");
                joinPoint.proceed(); //continue on the intercepted method
                System.out.println("Around after is running!");
                System.out.println("******");
           }


}
```

My Spring Configuration  applicationContext-aop.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="ma.nawarit.logger.LoggerBean" />

    <aop:config>

        <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect" >

            <!-- @Before -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore"
                expression="execution(public * *(..))" />

            <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" />

            <!-- @After -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAfter"
                expression="execution(public * *(..))" />

            <aop:after method="logAfter" pointcut-ref="pointCutAfter" />

            <!-- @AfterReturning -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAfterReturning"
                expression="execution(public * *(..))" />

            <aop:after-returning method="logAfterReturning" returning="result" 
                pointcut-ref="pointCutAfterReturning" />


            <!-- @AfterThrowing -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAfterThrowing"
                expression="execution(public * *(..))" />

            <aop:after-throwing method="logAfterThrowing" throwing="error" 
                pointcut-ref="pointCutAfterThrowing"  />


            <!-- @Around -->
            <aop:pointcut id="pointCutAround"
                expression="execution(public * *(..))" />

            <aop:around method="logAround" pointcut-ref="pointCutAround"  />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

My Web.xml context param

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext-manageable.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/applicationContext-engine.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/applicationContext-periodicProcess.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/applicationContext-jbpm.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/applicationContext-batch.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/applicationContextSecurity-jasypt-dynamic.xml,
            /WEB-INF/jasperSpring-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/conf/spring/applicationContext-aop.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

After i run my App i get this Error formal unbound in pointcut Please Help me i tried différents configurations but no result

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserManageableServiceBase' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/manageable/compagnie-applicationContext-manageable.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDao' while setting bean property 'dao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/dao/compagnie-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl#713616c0' of type [ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl#713616c0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/dao/compagnie-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/dao/compagnie-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl#713616c0' of type [ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl#713616c0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/dao/compagnie-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ma.nawarit.checker.compagnie.UserDaoImpl#713616c0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/dao/compagnie-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/conf/spring/global-applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:263)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:295)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:359)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 80 more
```

Comment: Have you defined your beans (userDao, etc. in your application_context?)

Comment: Yes it already mentioned in the applicationContext

Comment: Can you post it? Please, post too where are you using your annotation

Comment: I'm new at this i didn't understand what's your request is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@AfterReturning` declaration is incorrect, you forgot to specify the name of the argument containing the return value.

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="execution(public * *(..))", returning="result")
public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
...
}
```

Comment: You get the same error, or it doesn't work for another reason?

Comment: I get this error No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress

Comment: That means that you have a different problem, which implies that my answer probably solved your problem in your question, and now you have a different problem.

Comment: Thank you very much i identify my problem all configuration is correct but when i call spring context configuration in web.xml and run the app the application doesn't run the configuration. I don't know what i need the do